# Saving Drawing/Signature in AgilePoint to SharePoint List using JS

Tags: javascript, agilepoint

I'm working on AgilePoint platform and I'm trying to save drawing from form I've built into SharePoint List. So first of all I'm converting the drawing (signature) to URI code, and now I want to convert it to img file JPG/PNG or whatever.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaBLq.png

- this is the drawing(signature) i'm trying to convert to URI and then to png/jpg.

I've converted it to URI by this code:

```
function image() {
 var URI = 'x';
var options = {};
options.fieldId = 'Drawing1';
eFormHelper.getFieldValue (options, function (result) 
  { 
  if (result.isSuccess) //check if is success
    { 
    URI = result.data;
      
    }
});
}
```

- But now i don't know how to save it into SharePoint List.
  thank you for helping.